# DataTable 1.10, Column.render usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm having trouble understanding the different usage alternatives of the DataTable option [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)

As the docs state, the `render` option can be specified as a function (this is the alternative that I use), an object or a string.

In the last two cases, I can't make it work.

In my case, I have a data source like the following:

```
[ 
    { 
      id_sol: "10", 
      id_box: "1", 
      local: "8000",
      localDesc: "Testing",
      solic: null, 
      ts: "09/01/2016 00:00", 
      tipoDesc: "Rollo Testigo" 
    }
]
```

(An array of several objects with the above structure)

What I wanted to do is render `localDesc` in the column which corresponds to `local`. I can do this using the function alternative for `render`, but if I do:

```
columns: [
        {data:"local",
            render: "localDesc"
        },
        ...
    ]
```

It doesn't work. DataTables throws a "Requested unknown parameter 'local' for row 0".

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I didn't fully grasp about the `render` option?

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide a function to `render`, within which you have access to `data, type, row, meta`, what you probably need to something like this:

```
"render": function(data, type, row, meta){
    return row.localDesc;
}
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/ffeo9L4u/

Comment: Yes, that works. I was asking about the other 2 formats that the render options accepts, an object and a string.